# Status Code 403 from Spotify API When Requesting User's Top Tracks and Top Artists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

*Update I can request an artists albums with their id, error seems to only be coming from the /me endpoint*

Newer Developer here

Working on a react application that allows a user to log in to Spotify and then displays their top 10 tracks and top 10 artists.

I can login with no problem, but when I request a user top tracks and artists I get this response from the API:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Here's App.js:

```js
import WelcomeStatement from './WelcomeStatement';
import LogButton from './LogButton';
import Top10List from './Top10List';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

function App() {
  // set auth information
  const CLIENT_ID = '';
  const CLIENT_SECRET =  ''
  const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000';
  const AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
  const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';
  
  // create a spotify web api instance
  const spotifyNode = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
  })

  // declare state variables
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [artists, setArtists] = useState([]);
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  // getter functions for tracks and artists
  const getTracks = function() {
    let res = spotifyNode.getMyTopTracks('limit=10').then(res => console.log(res))
  }

  const getArtists = function() {
    let res = spotifyNode.getMyTopArtists('limit=10').then(res => console.log(res))
  }

  // capture url, trim to just the access token, set token equal to the access token
  // set isLoggedIn state to true and call getter functions
  useEffect(effect => {
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (!token && hash){
      token = hash.slice(1).split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
      console.log(token)
      hash = '';
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);  
      spotifyNode.setAccessToken(token)
      setIsLoggedIn(true)
      getTracks()
      getArtists()
    }

    setToken(token)
  }, [])

  // set content variable based on isLoggedIn state
  let content = (
    !isLoggedIn ? 
    <>
      <WelcomeStatement isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}></WelcomeStatement>
      <LogButton isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} setToken={setToken} clientId={CLIENT_ID} redirectUri={REDIRECT_URI} authEndpoint={AUTH_ENDPOINT} responseType={RESPONSE_TYPE}></LogButton>
    </>
    :
    <>
      <WelcomeStatement isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}></WelcomeStatement>
      <Box className='top-10s-ctr'>
        <Top10List title='Top 10 Artists'></Top10List>
        <Top10List title='Top 10 Songs'></Top10List>
      </Box>
      <LogButton isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} setToken={setToken} clientId={CLIENT_ID} redirectUri={REDIRECT_URI} authEndpoint={AUTH_ENDPOINT} responseType={RESPONSE_TYPE}></LogButton>
    </>
  )

  
  return (
    <Box className="App">
      {content}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's LogButton.js which performs the authorization:

```js
import './App.css';

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function LogButton(props) {
    const LOGIN_BUTTON_STYLES = {background: '#1DB954', borderRadius: '30px', p: '15px', fontWeight: 'bold'}

    const logout = () => {
        props.setToken('')
        window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
        props.setIsLoggedIn(false)
      }

    return (
        props.isLoggedIn ?
        <Button
            variant="contained" 
            sx={LOGIN_BUTTON_STYLES}
            onClick={logout}
        >
            Logout
        </Button>
        :
        <Button
            variant="contained" 
            sx={LOGIN_BUTTON_STYLES}
            href={`${props.authEndpoint}?client_id=${props.clientId}&redirect_uri=${props.redirectUri}&response_type=${props.responseType}`}
        >
            Login to Spotify
        </Button>
    )
}
```

The account has been added to my Spotify dashboard, which I thought was the issue at first.

I've also tried writing the request with `axios.get()` and `fetch()`, both had the same status code.

Is there something wrong with my authorization flow? Or is the request improperly formatted?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the scope param in my authorization request. When using the /me endpoint you must define what actions you want to perform on behalf of the user.

Here's an example of a scope param:

```
  const SCOPE = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-read-recently-played user-top-read';
```

And here are the available scopes from [Spotify's Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/)

Happy coding!